# Both browsers timeout. From the command line, I have Internet access

Tags: internet, browser

Suddenly both Firefox and Chrome time out. From the command line, both ping and nslookup work fine. I have rebooted and reset my router. I have a new ISP, Google fiber optic webpass. I have tried both wifi and Ethernet

Comment: Do you have Firefox VPN or any other proxy/VPN applications set up on your system with this ISP?  VPNs might cause issues like this.